# Java Arrays being overwritten by next element/value (Methods, Array)

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I've read a couple of thread before posting, however these thread that I have read seem to be much complex than my understanding.

Here are my codes,

### //InventoryApp (main)

```
package myInventoryPkg;

public class InventoryApp 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Inventory myInventory = new Inventory(100);
        Product myProduct = new Product();

        myProduct.setName("Pen");
        myProduct.setPrice(1.25);
        myProduct.setQuantity(50);
        myInventory.addProduct(myProduct);

        //System.out.println("Product    : " + myInventory.items[0].getName());
        //System.out.println("Current Size : " + myInventory.getCurrentSize()); //Size 1.
        //I am able to show "Pen" by printing the codes above when pointing to item[0]


        myProduct.setName("Paper");
        myProduct.setQuantity(500);
        myProduct.setPrice(12.85);
        myInventory.addProduct(myProduct);

        //System.out.println("Product    : " + myInventory.items[1].getName());
        //System.out.println("Current Size : " + myInventory.getCurrentSize()); //Size 2.
        //I am NOT able to show "Pen" by printing the codes above when pointing to item[0]
        //instead, whether I point to item[0] or item[1], the system shows me "Paper", which
        //should not be the case...

        /* (commented it due to the above error)
        for(int i = 0; i < myInventory.items.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Product  : " + myInventory.items[i].getName());
            System.out.println("Price    : " + myInventory.items[i].getPrice());
            System.out.println("Quantity : " + myInventory.items[i].getQuantity());
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        }
        */
    }

}
```

### //Inventory (methods)

```
package myInventoryPkg;

public class Inventory 
{
    Product[] items;
    private int currentSize;

    public Inventory(int inputMaxSize)
    {
        currentSize = 0;
        items = new Product[inputMaxSize];
    }

public boolean addProduct(Product inputProduct)
    {
        if(currentSize < items.length)
        {
            items[currentSize] = inputProduct; 
            currentSize++;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }   
    }

    public int getCurrentSize()
    {
        return currentSize;
    }

    public Product getProduct(int index)
    {
        return items[index];
    }
}
```

### //Product (methods)

```
package myInventoryPkg;

public class Product 
{
    private String name;
    private int quantity;
    private double price;

    public Product()
    {
        String inputName = "";
        int inputQuantity = 0;
        double inputPrice = 0.0;

        name = inputName;
        quantity = inputQuantity;
        price = inputPrice;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int getQuantity()
    {
        return quantity;
    }

    public double getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }

    public void setName(String inputName)
    {
        name = inputName;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int inputQuantity)
    {
        quantity = inputQuantity;
    }

    public void setPrice(double inputPrice)
    {
        price = inputPrice;
    }
}
```

--
I appreciate any help, and all my codes have been added.
Do note that I do not receive errors when running this application aside the wrong values the arrays is showing me, which seems to be my biggest problem.

Regards,
Yubin

--

Thread closed.

Comment: You need to create a new instance of MyProduct.  A good practice is to mark any instance created within a method as final and create new instance for a new entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate a new `Product`. You've only created one `Product` and you keep modifying that singular product,

```
Product myProduct = new Product(); // <-- a reference to a product.
myProduct.setName("Pen");
myProduct.setPrice(1.25);
myProduct.setQuantity(50);
myInventory.addProduct(myProduct); // <-- a copy of the reference.

myProduct = new Product(); // <-- create a new product.
// now you have a second product....
myProduct.setName("Paper");
myProduct.setQuantity(500);
myProduct.setPrice(12.85);
myInventory.addProduct(myProduct);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been cracking my head for the past 30 minutes! Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the same product object, again and again, to the list. So the list eventually has many references to a unique Product object, whose state is the last one. If you want several different products, you need to call `new Product()` several times.

Answer (score 0):

You're not creating a new instance of the Product class, so each time you call setSomething, you're just changing the existing instance, and when you add that instance to a new slot in the array, you're just creating a new alias. All of the items point to the same item in memory.